# Search syntax for searching matrix fields (in the CP)

Tags: matrix, control-panel, search

Looking for a way to search (in the CP), for elements where a matrixField is empty or not.

This *seems* to work:
- with matrix rows: `myMatrixField::*`
- without matrix rows: `-myMatrixField::*`

However, this *doesn't* work in the event that you have fuzzy enabled by default: https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default

Any other way to achieve this?